# unable to split audio using split_on_silence()

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, pydub

I've tried multiple combinations of min_silence_len and silence_thresh but it always returns chunk of length 1. Unable to understand, what am I missing ?

```
import speech_recognition as sr  
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence

# obtain audio from the microphone  
r = sr.Recognizer()
#r = sr.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")
with sr.Microphone() as source:
  print("Please wait. Calibrating microphone...")
  # listen for 5 seconds and create the ambient noise energy level
  r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5)
  print("Say something!")

audio = r.listen(source)
a = r.recognize_google(audio)
audio_chunks = split_on_silence(a, min_silence_len=30, silence_thresh=-5)
print(len(audio_chunks))
```

For Example:
When I say "What is wrong with this code" on the microphone. I am expecting the complete sentence to get divided in chunks as audio_chunks should be a array of words:
What || is || wrong || with || this || code

Actual result:
audio_chunk length =1
audio_chunk = ['What is worng with this code']

Comment: what is `r`? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: r is the recognizer object -> r = sr.Recognizer()

Comment: `r = sr.Recognizer()
#r = sr.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")
with sr.Microphone() as source:
  print("Please wait. Calibrating microphone...")
  # listen for 5 seconds and create the ambient noise energy level
  r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5)
  print("Say something!")
  audio = r.listen(source)`

Comment: an expert on google speech may help even by a fragment if code, but generally asking question requires a minimal, complete, verifiable example. can you do that? yours is not complete

Comment: Added complete code snnipet and provided an example for the expected result.

Comment: imagine someone wanting to replicate your error on a local computer.... she copies  your code to a local file, runs python on it and guess what error she gets? a complete minimal code in your question is a form of courtsy to people helpung you. sorry this is not about your original question

Comment: hint: add imports to code